# Pipe user input to another program

Tags: pipe

I know that running `cat` with no argument reflects the user input

```
$ cat
test
test
reflected
reflected
```

I want to pipe the reflected output to another program such as `base64`. The expected behavior is like so

```
$ cat | base64
test
dGVzdA==
another
YW5vdGhlcg==
```

I want this for encoding text line-by-line as I type, and/or send them over something like `nc`. However, when used like this, no output seems to be reflected and escaping with `ctrl+C` just terminates the whole thing without output

```
$ cat | base64
test
fail
^C
```

With everything working correctly, I should be able to establish an encoded/encrypted connection (very simple chat application) like so

```
# client
$ $CMD | encrypt | nc $SERVER $PORT
this is a test
multiple lines
^C

# host
$ nc -lvp | decrypt
this is a test
multiple lines
```

Similarly, I should be able to encode & save as follows

```
$ CMD | base64  | tee log_file
test
dGVzdA==
another
YW5vdGhlcg==
^C

$ cat log_file
dGVzdA==
YW5vdGhlcg==
```

Note that the whole thing should be a single pipe line. Using a loop wouldn't work well as `nc` would establish a new connection every iteration and `tee` without `-a` would overwrite the file every line (per iteration). I want 1 single instance of the final command (e.g. `nc`, `base64`) taking input pipe from `CMD` like with `cat` but with user input instead of a file.

I'm looking for a way to do said piping of user input line-by-line to another process, preferably as a short one-liner. How can I get such piping of user input?

Comment: There's a while-loop answer that was deleted, which you'd misunderstood going by your comment there, I think. `while read x; do echo "$x" | base64; done | nc ...` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @muru Your specific command does work as intended. However, I'm trying to split this command into 2 parts: (1) the read-and-reflect (here, the `while` loop), and (2) the target command (`base64`, `nc`, etc.) and make those 2 separate. This is so that anything that would take input from `stdin` can all be put on the same side for more complex implementations of such a pipe line.

Comment: I think there's a disconnect here. You have two target commands per invocation, not one - one that does line-by-line, and the second which takes the first's complete output. So you can put the `while` loop in a function which takes the first command as an argument, and then you pipe the output of the function to the second command.

Comment: The "target command" should be a single command or a chain of commands that takes input from `stdin`,  thus the pipe. This whole "target command" should have no part inside the `CMD`. I'm not looking for a way to chain the pipe with `base64` and `nc`, but rather a way to get (1) user input reflected and piped to `stdout` and thus another command (like `cat`) and (2) a way to take the `stdout` of said `CMD` and pipe it to another command or chain of commands. `cat` gives be the reflected output but that output for some reason doesn't get piped to the other command the way I want.

Comment: So, two target commands, (1) and (2), which tallies with what I said.

Comment: The (1) should not contain any of the "target commands" and its only function should be to pipe the user input into another command. Your example has `base64` inside that (1) part.

Comment: So parametrise it by using a function, like I said earlier.

Comment: @muru I undeleted the answer, I got lost with `nc` but was in the right path it seems.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```bsh
# this is an infinite loop, but can be changed to whatever you need
while true; do read x; echo "$x" | base64; done
```

Output:

```
foo
Zm9vCg==
bar
YmFyCg==
```

Comment: Trying this with `while true; do read x; echo "$x" | nc localhost 1337; done`, the piping doesn't persist and `nc` seems to only send the 1st line of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out why `cat | base64` doesn't work as I intended. `base64` needs to take in *all* of the input, terminated by (I think) an `EOF`. Since output from `cat` doesn't have the terminator, `base64` never stopped taking in and buffering the input, and `ctrl-C` terminates both `cat` and `base64`. Basically, `base64` is waiting for the output from `cat` to end with `EOF` but `cat` doesn't output `EOF`, so the encoded output never got to be returned. By using `cat << EOF | base64`, the user input is reflected and piped to `base64` but is only output once `EOF` is entered.

```bsh
$ cat << EOF | base64
pipe heredoc> ls
pipe heredoc> test
pipe heredoc> EOF
bHMKdGVzdAo=
```

On the other hand, `nc` takes in user input continuously and its inputs can be separated with `\n`. Therefore, the piping works with `cat | nc`. That's how `cat` and `nc` are often used to get shells in pentesting & CTFs

Bind shell

```bsh
# user
$ cat | nc $IP 1337

# target
$ nc -lp 1337
```

Reverse shell

```bsh
# user
$ cat | nc -lp 1337

# target
$ nc $IP 1337
```

Due to the difference in buffering and terminators between applications (`base64` and `nc`), the pipe line I wanted to make isn't possible without some adjustments. The final chain can be achieved by putting commands with return all output in one go (e.g. `base64`) inside a `while` loop, and commands which take input line-by-line (e.g. `nc` on the right of the pipe)

```bsh
# code courtesy of @muru in the comments
while read x; do
   echo "$x" | base64
done | nc
```